# What is the best WebBrowser control that allows one proxy per instance?

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I am making a multi-threaded [workers] application. Each thread should have it's own Non-GUI WebBrowser that Navigates to a web page and writes data to fields and click a button. I also need each WebBrowser to have it's own proxy. I tried the classic Windows.Forms.WebBrowser but I got stuck at the proxy part as it depends on IE global settings which won't work in my case. Any recommendations are welcome.

note: I tried doing it through HttpWebRequest/Response but it will never work as the data to be passed to the page contains a field called [ab_test_data] which gets its value from javascript code that calculate the value according to AB testing which I don't even fully understand. So a WebBrowser would be my best solution, unless someone can tell me how to convert that Javascript code that calculates ab_test_data to C# code. The algorithm used by the page I am trying to access is really sophisticated.

note2: ab_test_data value depends on Window.Event and Timestamp which can't be simulated on a httpWebRequest/Response.

note3: I tried Gecko, But it won't let me do anything to the webPage unless GeckoWebBrowser is drawn on the form (which I don't want).
Any solutions are welcome.

edit: If you know any WebBrowser that works like I want in any different language (Maybe Java) I would like to know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a very important question.  Chrome is finally getting enough attention that there are probably a few new .NET bindings for it.  Thanks for asking.  Community wiki maybe?

Comment: @Chad: I think this question is far too specialized to serve as a general "What is the best browser to embed in a .NET application" keystone question. When was the last time you used a browser without a GUI?

Comment: @Cody Gray - I'm the wrong person to ask that question :-)  I am actually developing a .NET app and using invisible WebBrowsers (IE) in it, right now.  That's what attracted me to the question in the first place, because I've been looking for a faster alternative to WebBrowser/IE.

Comment: @Chad: Fascinating. From my perspective, you two are both describing something like an MP3 player that doesn't play music.

Comment: @Cody Gray - Well, it's not ideal - that's for sure!  I basically want a (simple to use) invisible DOM and JavaScript parser/interpreter.  The OP basically wants the same, with some nice proxy configuration options.

Comment: @Cody Gray, Having an mp3 that doesn't play music is definitely useful to some people. Everything has a use.

Comment: The problem is not that you can't use `webrequest`, but that you do not know how to translate the javascript. I suggest that you ask for help with the javascript instead. It would give you a much more robust solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[CefSharp: .Net binding for the Chromium Embedded Framework](https://github.com/ataranto/CefSharp)

Comment: I can't find any documentation. I can't even convert their sample project to VS2010.

Comment: What's the difference between CefSharp and WebKit.NET?  Doesn't Chrome (and hence CefSharp) use WebKit?

Comment: I'd say speed and features.  For some reason Webkit.NET seems much slower than WebKit proper whilst CefSharp has near comparable speed to Chrome, this might have something to do with Chromium using V8 for JS.  CefSharp is pretty new and it already has many features that WebKit.NET doesn't have or didn't have when I set out.  E.g. RunScript, resource load interception and the ability to bind .Net objects into the DOM.  All that said CefSharp is still at an alpha level stage where as WebKit.NET looks to have a more stable API and product.  Clearly I'm biased though ;-)

Comment: The linked repository (https://github.com/chillitom/CefSharp) has been inactive for a while - active development can be found at https://github.com/ataranto/CefSharp

Answer (score 1):

use http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Can I write text to fields and click a button on an invisible WebKit browser? I don't think so.

Comment: As I mentioned, I need the browser to be invisible because I will be using many browsers, one on each thread. When I tried using Windows.Forms.WebBrowser, I used "new WebBrowser()" to create the object and never drew it to the form. I need it to be that way.

Comment: Please read my question well. I wish I can use HttpWebRequest, But ABTesting is keeping me away from doing so. Because it's generated at the client browser once he submits. It even depends on Window.Event and Browser timestamp which I can't get without a browser. HttpWebRequest won't let me do that.

Comment: @erinus - any reasons (besides performance) not to use an invisible browser?

Comment: Many browser's rendering engine or security policy do not allow access or change data of some html element in invisible webbrowser or invisible webbrowser control.

Comment: wow, that sounds pretty strange.  Do you know if Chrome/CefSharp/WebKit.NET/IE do this?  Is there a page or way to find out?

Comment: Webkit.Net can't, I just tried it. It doesn't even Navigate when it's not drawn. Windows.Forms.WebBrowser can.

Comment: @Chad, I say some element, like input[type=file], if you set it invisible, you can't set file path into it and upload file to server. in general situation, using invisible browser is OK, but sometimes I'll get strange error or no action by invisible webbrowser. I don't know why, so I just give a suggestion.

Comment: @deadlock, there's a complex solution, create a vitual desktop, and open your WebKit/Gecko embeded window in virtual desktop, now user can't see those windows, but they're not invisible.

Comment: @erinus, More information on how to do that will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @erinus, Please note that my main problem is setting a proxy for each individual webBrowser. I can run The normal webBrowser without drawing it unlike Gecko,Webkit. And I guess Gecko,Webkit doesn't have the option to change the proxy. Correct me.

Comment: see this page. you can create your own virtual desktop and create process in it. But it use Win32 API. So you must write unmanaged code in .NET Application. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2006/07/05/656197.aspx

Comment: @deadlock, I don't develop any webbrowser-proxy application, so I can't promise it's work. But if Gecko/WebKit can set their proxy, using VirtualDesktop to open the window can hide the window and Windows still draw them in background.

Answer (score 1):

As a question that may help, I wonder why browsers don't allow a proxy per (say) window/tab?  I think a lot of it is because of lack of usefulness with respect to development time.

It may also be because the browsers [presumably] have centralized engines for things like web requests and caches, etc...  Perhaps, allowing a proxy per window and/or tab would fundamentally alter the design of the modern browser and or have negative performance impacts.  I don't really know.  To illustrate the point further, consider things like Incognito mode and Private Browsing.  In these cases, the browsers have, at least, conceptually made separate caches per windows...but I still bet an Incognito window and a standard window (in Chrome) use the same underlying web request engine.

Right now there are so many people who want a JavaScript and DOM parser and interpreter.  Projects like the [HtmlAgility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and [Jint](http://jint.codeplex.com/) are helping, but there doesn't seem to be a unified and standard solution; at least not one with the simplicity of a web browser.

**[rant below]...**

Unfortunately, projects like Jint and HtmlAgility are worrisome. For one, they're not IE, Chrome, Safari or FireFox.  You don't exactly know what you're getting yourself into.  For instance, you know that in Chrome page xyz.com loads and renders perfectly.  You can fire up FireFox and see that maybe something is not quite the same and so on with the other browsers.  But, with these libraries you don't really know what if not everything is working right (there's no visual display to do a quick check).  Plus, who knows what pace they're being developed at.  Do they keep up with HTML5?  Do they lag behind the major browsers?  What about performance?  Even more so, browsers already have things like caching and performance enhancements, which I doubt you'll get with individual libraries.

The best browser control would of course be something like:

```
IWebBrowser browser = new IE();
IWebBrowser browser = new Chrome();
IWebBrowser browser = new Safari();
IWebBrowser browser = new FireFox();
```

I think that is a dream, unfortunately.  For one, what if you ever wanted to load plug-ins with these?  What about user profiles, user logins, and so on?  I think most of us just want the muscle of the browsers without these extras.

I really do hope that you find a good Chrome solution.  I don't know what, if any, luck you'll have in the FireFox realm - maybe you can keep us updated?  These solutions are evolving so quickly - I had never even heard of CefSharp or WebKit.NET before today and I looked for the same thing (Chrome and/or FireFox .NET browsers) several months ago for my own use.  It would be great if a lot of people got together, made a standard interface and then each company built their embedded browser against the spec.  Here's to wishing.